# How to convert an array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

please, i want to convert my array of object to an object or to json.
This is a sample preview.

```
var data = [ 
       {"code":"M","montant":"2000","title":"Masculin"},                                                 
      {"code":"F","montant":"1000","title":"Femini"},
      {"code":"X","montant":"5000","title":"Others"}
];
```

I want it to

```
var data = {"code":"M","montant":"2000","title":"Masculin"},                                                 
          {"code":"F","montant":"1000","title":"Femini"},
          {"code":"X","montant":"5000","title":"Others"};
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: well what you want to convert it to is not valid.... What is your real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, but the syntax that you desire is not valid JavaScript. Are you trying to print the output to a text file?

Comment: The syntax is actually valid (it uses [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)), but it will set `data` to the last object in the list. Is this actually what you want? Perhaps if you told us your end goal, we could help you.

Comment: Please edit your answer any add an explanation of what you're trying to do. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I believed that too but tried it and it does give sintax error

Comment: Oh, right, because `var data = ` is part of the first statement. It then goes to {"code"...} and that's not a valid statement. Never mind :).

Comment: There's no benefit to converting your lovely array into some weird object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst it is not totally clear what you are intending to achieve, here is a way to construct an object having attributes that match the code from the data array entries. The approach here uses the fact that you can address an object attribute using ["attrname"], so we walk through your array and use one of the attributes of the array entries to provide the attribute of the new object.

Note that if you have multiple entries in the source array with the same code value then the final entries will override the earlier entries.

The output looks like:

```
{
  "M": {
    "code": "M",
    "montant": "2000",
    "title": "Masculin"
  },
  "F": {
    "code": "F",
    "montant": "1000",
    "title": "Femini"
  },
  "X": {
    "code": "X",
    "montant": "5000",
    "title": "Others"
  }
}
```

```js
var data = [ 
       {"code":"M","montant":"2000","title":"Masculin"},                                                 
      {"code":"F","montant":"1000","title":"Femini"},
      {"code":"X","montant":"5000","title":"Others"}
];

var newObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1){
  var obj = data[i]
  newObj[obj.code] = obj;
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can achieve this by this way...

```js
var data = [ 
       {"code":"M","montant":"2000","title":"Masculin"},                                                 
      {"code":"F","montant":"1000","title":"Femini"},
      {"code":"X","montant":"5000","title":"Others"}
];

var myObj = {};

data.map(function(item, idx) {
 myObj['key'+idx] = item;
});

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Please don't guess as to what the OP wants. Just wait until the OP responds to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The second code example is not valid javascript. If you want to convert your array use.

`var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);` to convert this to a string.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your answer. What i want is this

Answer (score 0):

The following is **not** valid syntax.

```
var data = {"code":"M","montant":"2000","title":"Masculin"},                                                 
          {"code":"F","montant":"1000","title":"Femini"},
          {"code":"X","montant":"5000","title":"Others"};
```

If you want to store multiple objects in a variable, you need an array. To represent your data in JSON it would be.

```
{
    "data": [
        {"code":"M","montant":"2000","title":"Masculin"},                                                 
        {"code":"F","montant":"1000","title":"Femini"},
        {"code":"X","montant":"5000","title":"Others"}
    ]
}
```

You can convert your `data` array to JSON by doing the following:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```